# Как перенести папку у которой есть общий доступ по сети за другой пк?

Tags: windows-8

решили обновить пк, на старом стоит windows xp, купили новый на windows 8. Есть рабочая локальная папка с общим доступов в диске C (на старом). Как сделать так чтобы эта же папка была доступна за windows 8? т.к. там стоит база access и все такое? прописать имя компьютера такое же?

Answer (score 1):

```
net use x: \\server_name\source
```

Подключиться к ресурсу с машины \server_name, ресурс \source
Т.е. клиенту при совпадении имени сервера, имени ресурса, совпадении прав доступа и разрешений чтение/запись абсолютно безразлично к какому серверу он подключится. 
**Особое внимание** обратить на права доступа на файловой системе и в Центре управления сетями и общим доступом.

Comment: нет вы не поняли походу, есть 5 компов, у одного из них есть папка exchage, в этой папке есть база access к которой подключаются все остальные компы, если я вырублю этот комп и вместо него поставлю другой и создам папку с похожим именем, расшарю на всех и закину туда базу, то ведь не будет соединения с этой базой?